# Using async to handle promise from Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm struggling with handling a call to the Google Calendar API.  I've slightly modified the Node.js quickstart from the Google API docs for my needs.  I'm trying to retrieve all events from the calendar but when I try to await the return, all I get is `Promise { <pending> }`.  Is there a better way to wait for the call or is there something I'm totally missing?

```
async function listEvents() {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: apiKey});
  return await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: <calendarID>,
    timeMin: oneWeekAgo,
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      events.forEach(el => console.log(el.summary))
      // console.log(events)
      // eventList = events
      return events
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

FWIW, the events do eventually log to the console, I just can't figure out how to get the function to wait for that promise to resolve before returning.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. I _think_ what you're trying to say is that you are getting `Promise { <pending> }` as a result of calling `listEvents`. Is that correct? If so, it's because `listEvents` is marked as an `asycn` function. All `async` functions implicitly return a `Promise`. So, you need to `await` your `listEvents` call, or call `.then` on it. Also, unless you are intentionally trying to throw network errors, you never need to do `return await` since, as mentioned above, using `async` will wrap the function return in a `Promise` anyways.

Comment: well your aync function will obviously return a ` Promise {<pending>}`, use a .then() for it to show events after it is resolved?

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, it's returning `Promise { <pending> }` .  The original example didn't return anything, just logged the result.  I added the `async` on line 1 and `await` on line 3 and the `return events` at the bottom.  I assume the pending promise it's returning is the call to `calendar.events.list()` since when I remove async/await, it returns `undefined` (and hovering on .list() says it's a GaxiosPromise).

If I added `.then()`, would it then be `listEvents().then(<do something with the return>)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use await with a callback style. I guess if you just remove the callback function and put await it will return you the details

```
async function listEvents() {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: apiKey});
  const res = await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: <calendarID>,
    timeMin: oneWeekAgo,
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  });
  const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      events.forEach(el => console.log(el.summary))
      // console.log(events)
      // eventList = events
      return events
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this still gives me `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: you mean `res` is pending? or response of listEvents? if it is listEvents which is returning promise, it is a desired behavior. You need to await that or use then

Comment: I should clarify, I was trying to console.log(listEvents()) which now seems obvious that it's not an async function.

Further, this is a module called by express:

`app.get('/events', async (req, res) => {
    let asyncResponse = await getEvents();
    res.send(asyncResponse)
});`

And now, using Postman, I'm getting the proper JSON!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is the TypeScript code that I use to fetch calendar events

```js
let results: GaxiosResponse<calendar_v3.Schema$Events>;
const maxResults: any = process.env.MAX_CALENDAR_RESULTS;
try {
    this.logger.info('Fetching events for primary calendar id');

    results = await gcalClient.events.list({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString()),
        maxResults,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
     });
     this.logger.info('Successfully fetched calendar events');
} catch (err) {
    this.logger.error('Error encountered while fetching events');
    this.logger.error(err);
    return err;
}
// Extract the Calendar Events from the response received
const eventList: calendar_v3.Schema$Event[] = results.data.items;
```

You can add this in an `async` function and return `eventList`, which will make the return type of the function to be `Promise<calendar_v3.Schema$Event[]>`

Now, wherever you call the function, use `await` or `.then()` to get the calendar events

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not familiar with TS but I did try converting it back to vanillaJS

Comment: Worth learning. Typescript makes it very easy to avoid such issues.